# How do I get my page to remember user's last action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a search form which allows users to search for items on the page.

There is also another form with checkboxes that allows users to refine their searches with the hope of reducing the number of search results.

For instance, if I enter McCland on the search box and 13 results marching McCland are returned, I can click on `Advanced search` and a bunch of checkboxes are rendered.

I can then check `"Street"`, `"Road"`, `"LandMarks"`, etc. I can then click search on McCland again.

This time, only addresses with Street or Road or LandMarks will be displayed if available.

This works great.

Then there is a `Remember This Action` icon.

My biggest challenge so far is to allow users to click on this `Remember This Action` icon and save their current results.

This way, next time they visit the page, the results they searched for previously are presented to them unless they choose to search with another option.

If they click on this `Remember This Action` icon, they will be prompted with a message explaining that they are about to save their current Results.

They can click Yes to save or Cancel to not save.

I suspect this will be done with cookies(jquery or Javascriot) but I am not sure how to do this.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into `localStorage`/`sessionStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a jQuery solution you could use the JQuery Cookie Plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You're code might look something like this:

```
//Set the action
$.cookie('last_action', 'the_action');

//Get the action
var last_action = $.cookie('last_action');
if (typeof last_action != 'undefined') {
    // show last action
} else {
   //show default
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ryan.

Let's assume from my example above that I just by address of McCland with Streets, Roads, and LandMarks and I wish to remember what I searched for and the results next time I visit the page, how will I modify your code?

Ian, I am still reading up on the link you provided. Thank you.

Comment: save the search field text in one cookie and then save a json array of the checked checkboxes in another cookie. (Alternatively you could make a new cookie for the value of each check box.) When the page loads check if the cookie(s) are set and fill in the search field and check the boxes based on the saved values.

Comment: sorry, I don't get what you mean. @Ryan, the examples on that link are very complicated.